# How can I change the default start and end of the day?

Tags: javascript, typescript, datetime, momentjs

So the day starts are 12AM and ends at 11.59.59 PM. I have a use case where I would like to change that behavior and have the day start at say 10 AM and end at 9.59.59.

Is there a way to do this in native javascript date or in moment.js?

Comment: No. You need to use an offset and calculate it yourself.

Comment: @JanPfeifer Yeah that's true. I found a solution myself that involves some arithmetic. I will post it here shorty incase any one else faces this issue

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has no concept of "start of day" or "end of day". It creates date objects with a time value based on the provided parameters, that's it.

You could create your own function to return dates for default times. The following creates a date for start of day based on:

1. If the time is before startOfDay, the start is set to startOfDay on the previous day
2. Otherwise it's set to startOfDay on the current day.

Similarly for end of day:

1. If the date is on or after startOfDay, the end is set to endOfDay the following day
2. Otherwise it's set to endOfDay on the current day

The start and end could be parameterised to set the start and end of day times.

```js
// Return a new date set to 10 hrs
// If the input is before startOfDay, then the date is set
// to the previous day at 10. 
function startOfDay(date = new Date(), sod = 10) {
  return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 
    date.getDate() + (date.getHours() < sod? -1 : 0), sod);
}

// Return a new date set to 1 second before startOfDay
// If the input is after startOfDay, the date is set to
// tomorrow
function endOfDay(date = new Date()) {
  let end = startOfDay(date);
  end.setDate(end.getDate() + (end < date? 1 : 0));
  end.setSeconds(end.getSeconds() - 1, 0);
  return end;
}

// Example
let dates = [
  new Date(2023,0,10,9),  // Start is on 9 Jan
  new Date(2023,0,10,11), // End is on 11 Jan
].forEach(date =>
  console.log(`Date : ${date.toLocaleString()}` +
    `\nStart: ${startOfDay(date).toLocaleString()}` +
    `\nEnd  : ${endOfDay(date).toLocaleString()}`
  )
);
```